# Elasticsearch Query and ElasticsearchCrudRepository Different pageable results

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have this query in **elasticsearch** which is giving correct results as expected but when I am trying to search via **ElasticsearchCrudRepository** using springboot, it is giving different results in random order

I searched on github, other stackoverflow questions some said it was version issue but I am using same version of spring-data-elasticsearch as well my elasticsearch

**ElasticsearchCrudRepository Query :**

```
@Component
public interface MedicineRepository extends ElasticsearchCrudRepository<Medicine, String> {

    @Query("{ \"function_score\" :{ \"query\":{ \"bool\": { \"must_not\": [ { \"match\": { \"status\": \"Inactive\" } }, { \"match\": { \"status\": \"Pending\" } } ], \"must\": [ { \"match\": { \"location\": \"?1\" } }, { \"bool\": { \"should\": [ { \"multi_match\": { \"query\": \"?0\", \"type\": \"best_fields\", \"fields\": [ \"name^5\", \"brand_name^3\" ], \"boost\": 1, \"fuzziness\": \"AUTO\", \"prefix_length\": 2 } }, { \"multi_match\": { \"query\": \"?0\", \"type\": \"phrase_prefix\", \"fields\": [ \"name^5\", \"brand_name^3\" ], \"boost\": 3 } }, { \"multi_match\": { \"query\": \"?0\", \"type\": \"phrase_prefix\", \"fields\": [ \"sku\" ], \"boost\": 5 } } ] } } ] } }, \"boost\": \"2\", \"functions\": [ { \"filter\": { \"match\": { \"status\": \"Active\" } }, \"weight\": 2 } ], \"max_boost\": 10, \"score_mode\": \"max\", \"boost_mode\": \"sum\", \"min_score\" : 0 } }")
    Page<Medicine> findByLocationAnd_SkuOrNameOrBrand(String query, String location, Pageable pageable);

}
```

**Normal ElasticSearch Query :**

```
{
"query" : 
    {
        "function_score" :{
            "query":{
      "bool": {
        "must_not": [
          {
            "match": {
              "status": "Inactive"
            }
          },
          {
            "match": {
              "status": "Pending"
            }
          }
        ],
        "must": [
          {
            "match": {
              "location": "Jaipur"
            }
          },
          {
            "bool": {
              "should": [
                {
                  "multi_match": {
                    "query": "crozin",
                    "type": "best_fields",
                    "fields": [
                      "name^5",
                      "brand_name^3"
                    ],
                    "boost": 1,
                    "fuzziness": "AUTO",
                    "prefix_length": 2
                  }
                },
                {
                  "multi_match": {
                    "query": "crozin",
                    "type": "phrase_prefix",
                    "fields": [
                      "name^5",
                      "brand_name^3"
                    ],
                    "boost": 3
                  }
                },
                {
                  "multi_match": {
                    "query": "crozin",
                    "type": "phrase_prefix",
                    "fields": [
                      "sku"
                    ],
                    "boost": 5
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
      "boost": "2", 
      "functions": [
          {
              "filter": { "match": { "status": "Active" } },
              "weight": 2
          }
      ],
      "max_boost": 10,
      "score_mode": "max",
      "boost_mode": "sum",
      "min_score" : 0
  }
        }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to log the query generated from the repository?

Comment: yep, since it is native query so it is same, i am calling **medicineRepository.findByLocationAnd_SkuOrNameOrBrand(query, location, pageable)**;